macOS tests failing because of different file order in unzipping/entries
I am attempting to make some changes to a library called ExcelJS. Right now I am trying to ensure all tests pass. For some reason, the one issue that keeps me from passing mostly everything is a weird macOS difference in the order in which files are read.
Here we can see that I added some logging to the workflow running this test to show that the value SharedStrings is undefined. On top of this, I can see that the XML file containing the SharedStrings values isn't even read. Before reading the worksheet, it should first get to a file inside the xl/ dir called xl/sharedStrings.xml. The other values are being read fine at the same depth. There are other tests that do this and they succeed perfectly fine.
Missing Shared Strings
Here is a code snippet of where the files get read:
async *parse(input, options) {
    if (options) this.options = options;
  
    // Turn input into a stream. If string stream then we good!
    const stream = (this.stream = this._getStream(input || this.input));
  
    //parse Zip stream
    const zip = unzip.Parse({forceStream: true});
    stream.pipe(zip);

    // worksheets, deferred for parsing after shared strings reading
    const waitingWorkSheets = [];

    // Something wrong here with order of operations or something.
    for await (const entry of iterateStream(zip)) {
      log('entryPath ', entry.path);
      let match;
      let sheetNo;
      switch (entry.path) {
        case '_rels/.rels':
          break;
        case 'xl/_rels/workbook.xml.rels':
          await this._parseRels(entry);
          break;
        case 'xl/workbook.xml':
          await this._parseWorkbook(entry);
          break;
        case 'xl/sharedStrings.xml':
          yield* this._parseSharedStrings(entry);
          break;
        case 'xl/styles.xml':
          await this._parseStyles(entry);
          break;
        default:
          if (entry.path.match(/xl\/worksheets\/sheet\d+[.]xml/)) {
            match = entry.path.match(/xl\/worksheets\/sheet(\d+)[.]xml/);
            sheetNo = match[1];
            if (this.sharedStrings && this.workbookRels) {
              yield* this._parseWorksheet(iterateStream(entry), sheetNo);
            } else {
              // create temp file for each worksheet
              await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                tmp.file((err, path, fd, tempFileCleanupCallback) => {
                  if (err) {
                    return reject(err);
                  }
                  waitingWorkSheets.push({sheetNo, path, tempFileCleanupCallback});

                  const tempStream = fs.createWriteStream(path);
                  tempStream.on('error', reject);
                  entry.pipe(tempStream);
                  return tempStream.on('finish', () => {
                    return resolve();
                  });
                });
              });
            }
          } else if (entry.path.match(/xl\/worksheets\/_rels\/sheet\d+[.]xml.rels/)) {
            match = entry.path.match(/xl\/worksheets\/_rels\/sheet(\d+)[.]xml.rels/);
            sheetNo = match[1];
            yield* this._parseHyperlinks(iterateStream(entry), sheetNo);
          }
          break;
      }
      entry.autodrain();
    }



I have looked into the test that performs this and it looks very similar to other tests that do the same thing. All these tests run fine on the Windows and Linux actions but macOS seems to have a weird quirk with directories.
I have a feeling that although the code snippet is included, it has something to do with either file names or the library used for unzip called unzipper.
